# Checkbox checked using Zend Form

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

IN this way checkbox is created

```
 $is_conveyance_required = new Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox(FORM_CHECKBOX_PREFIX . 'is_conveyance_required', array());

   $is_conveyance_required->addDecorators(array(
        array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'label')),
        array('Label', array('tag' => '')),
   ));

   $is_conveyance_required->setValue(1);
   $is_conveyance_required->setChecked( true );
   $this->addElement($is_conveyance_required);
```

and how form populating

```
$personal_form->populate($personal_data);
```

But zend form not populating checkbox...

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="chk_is_conveyance_required" name="chk_is_conveyance_required">
```

[image]

Here is $personal_data array img

Comment: Cross check that `$personal_data` must have key & value with same name of your checkbox

Comment: it have the same name as checkbox but value 1

Comment: Than it should work.Can you post the name ? I assume it must have `FORM_CHECKBOX_PREFIX` too in that.

Comment: it just a prefix to chk "chk_is_conveyance_required"... yeah it should work but

Comment: @Rikesh question has been updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply not working how you expect it to operate.

From the Zend Manual:

> By default, the checked value is '1', and the unchecked value '0'. You
>   can specify the values to use using the setCheckedValue() and
>   setUncheckedValue() accessors, respectively. Additionally, setting the
>   value sets the checked property of the checkbox. You can query this
>   using isChecked() or simply accessing the property. Using the
>   setChecked($flag) method will both set the state of the flag as well
>   as set the appropriate checked or unchecked value in the element.
>   Please use this method when setting the checked state of a checkbox
>   element to ensure the value is set properly.

You could do some workaround by using something like this (untested!) in you controller as addition to `popuplate()`

```
if($personal_form->is_conveyance_required->getValue() == 1) {
   $personal_form->is_conveyance_required->setChecked(true);
}
```